# Checkstyle eclipse plugin: error cannot initialize module TreeWalker Token "WILDCARD_TYPE"

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I have a problem with eclipse checkstyle plugin, i just installed this one and when i execute checkstyle-configuration with sun_checkstyle(eclipse) on java file, i have this error:

> cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Token "WILDCARD_TYPE" was not
>   found in Acceptable tokens list in check
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.whitespace.WhitespaceAroundCheck@2261fbd
>   cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Token "WILDCARD_TYPE" was not
>   found in Acceptable tokens list in check
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.whitespace.WhitespaceAroundCheck@2261fbd

But when i use checkstyle configuration : Sun Checks or Google Checks, it's works.
Do you have a solution ?
Thanks, Neyoh

Comment: I've just come across this too, the normal Sun checks work, so I guess the difference is to be found with a diff..... 

Sitting here pressing F5 until somebody answers :)

Comment: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/853#issuecomment-86942524

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is in the xml file sun_checks_eclipse.xml, found in your plugins folder for checkstyle (e.g. .\eclipse\plugins\net.sf.eclipsecs.core_xxxxxx):

```
<module name="WhitespaceAround">
        <property name="tokens" value="ASSIGN,BAND,BAND_ASSIGN,BOR,BOR_ASSIGN,BSR,BSR_ASSIGN,BXOR,BXOR_ASSIGN,COLON,DIV,DIV_ASSIGN,EQUAL,GE,GT,LAND,LCURLY,LE,LITERAL_ASSERT,LITERAL_CATCH,LITERAL_DO,LITERAL_ELSE,LITERAL_FINALLY,LITERAL_FOR,LITERAL_IF,LITERAL_RETURN,LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED,LITERAL_TRY,LITERAL_WHILE,LOR,LT,MINUS,MINUS_ASSIGN,MOD,MOD_ASSIGN,NOT_EQUAL,PLUS,PLUS_ASSIGN,QUESTION,RCURLY,SL,SLIST,SL_ASSIGN,SR,SR_ASSIGN,STAR,STAR_ASSIGN,LITERAL_ASSERT,TYPE_EXTENSION_AND,WILDCARD_TYPE"/>
    </module>
```

Simply remove the last entry WILDCARD_TYPE

I suspect the people writing checkstyle assume something that isn't correct, e.g. a specific version of Eclipse.

Anyway, I had it 5 minutes ago, I changed the entry above and it works now.

Comment: The error is even in their [most recent code](http://sourceforge.net/p/eclipse-cs/git/ci/6b37bcd6d4e127ad8bbf95e7e328c0ee2459c836/tree/net.sf.eclipsecs.core/sun_checks_eclipse.xml#l133) (at the time of this writing).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is not any "WILDCARD_TYPE" token available for WhitespaceAroundCheck.

List of the tokens which you can use are as below:

ASSIGN, BAND, BAND_ASSIGN, BOR, BOR_ASSIGN, BSR, BSR_ASSIGN, BXOR, BXOR_ASSIGN, COLON, DIV, DIV_ASSIGN, DO_WHILE, EQUAL, GE, GT, LAND, LCURLY, LE, LITERAL_ASSERT, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_RETURN, LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED, LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_WHILE, LOR, LT, MINUS, MINUS_ASSIGN, MOD, MOD_ASSIGN, NOT_EQUAL, PLUS, PLUS_ASSIGN, QUESTION, RCURLY, SL, SLIST, SL_ASSIGN, SR, SR_ASSIGN, STAR, STAR_ASSIGN, TYPE_EXTENSION_AND

For more information, you can have a look on our website: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_whitespace.html

Here, go to link, find "whitespacearound", you will find description for how to configure check for it. There is also information about each token if you want. just click on it.

If you have any other problem regarding, please let me know.

Thanks,

Bhavik

Answer (score 2):

token was added accepted list, fix was released http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/releasenotes.html#Release_6.5